# FullCalendar fc-more shows lots of duplicates in popup

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar and have a persistent bug with the fc-more links showing duplicates of the events being listed in the calendar.

The underlying mysql call does not produce duplicates. I think something in the calendar is creating duplicates, when events stretch across multiple days.  Unsure.  Interestingly, the number being displayed for fc-more is accurate, but once clicked, the popup produces duplicates.

[image: fc-more link]

I've attached a couple images to show what is happening.  I am wondering if anyone has run into similar issues.

[image: popup contents]

Here is the code that generates the feed data

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $uniqueid = base64_encode($row['id']);
    $a_json_row["id"] = $row['JobID'];
    $projectid = base64_encode($row['JobID']);
    $company = new Company();
    $company->load($mysqli,$row['CompanyID']);
    $a_json_row["start"] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['ShowOpen']));
    $a_json_row["end"] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['ShowClose']));
    $show = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['Show']));
    $project = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['JobID']));
    $mycompany = htmlentities(stripslashes($company->CompanyName));
    $BoothSize = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['BoothSize']));
    if($userid == ''){                       
        $user = new User();
        $user->load($mysqli, $row['AccountManager']);
        $initials = getInitials($user->name);
        $initials = "($initials)";
    }else{
        $initials = '';
    }
    $a_json_row["title"] = "$initials $BoothSize $project"; // $mycompany 

    if($row['Status'] == 7){             
            $a_json_row["color"] = htmlentities("#F1C40F");  // yellow
            $a_json_row["textColor"] = htmlentities('black');             
    }elseif(($row['Status'] == 6)||($row['Status'] == 2)){    
            $a_json_row["color"] = htmlentities("#1a6fad");
            $a_json_row["textColor"] = htmlentities('white');
    }elseif(($row['Status'] == 8)||($row['Status'] == 9)){    
            $a_json_row["color"] = htmlentities("#93AFBF");   // bluish
            $a_json_row["textColor"] = htmlentities('white');
    }elseif($row['Status'] == 4){    
            $a_json_row["color"] = htmlentities("#28B463");  // green
            $a_json_row["textColor"] = htmlentities('white');
    }elseif($row['Status'] == 1){    
            $a_json_row["color"] = htmlentities("#beb098");  // tan
            $a_json_row["textColor"] = htmlentities('white');
    }elseif($row['Status'] == 13){    
            $a_json_row["color"] = htmlentities("#922B21");   // red
            $a_json_row["textColor"] = htmlentities('white');
    }else{    // "Opportunity" = 1
            $a_json_row["color"] = htmlentities("#717D7E");  // gray
            $a_json_row["textColor"] = htmlentities('white');
    }   

    $a_json_row["url"] = "project.php?j=$projectid";
    array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
}
```

And here is the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10),
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: 'include/feed.php',
        eventClick: function(event) {
          if (event.url) {
            window.open(event.url);
            return false;
          }
        }
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: function(callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'include/feed.php',
                success: function(doc) {
                    var events = [];
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function(){
                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'), // will be parsed
                            url: $(this).attr('url'),
                            color: $(this).attr('color'),
                            textColor: $(this).attr('textColor')
                        });
                    });
                    callback(events);
                }
            });
        }
    });       
});
```

Here is some sample data

```
[{"id":"100041","start":"2019-07-30","end":"2019-07-31","title":"(JG) permanent install-office 100041","color":"#F1C40F","textColor":"black","url":"link.php?j=MTAwMDQx"},{"id":"100063","start":"2019-01-13","end":"2019-01-15","title":"(TJ) 20x20 100063","color":"#717D7E","textColor":"white","url":"link.php?j=MTAwMDYz"},{"id":"100070","start":"2019-02-12","end":"2019-02-14","title":"(KS) 50x80 100070","color":"#717D7E","textColor":"white","url":"link.php?j=MTAwMDcw"},{"id":"100129","start":"2019-05-20","end":"2019-05-22","title":"(AB) 20 x 30 100129","color":"#93AFBF","textColor":"white","url":"link.php?j=MTAwMTI5"},{"id":"100131","start":"2019-06-19","end":"2019-06-21","title":"(ME) 10x10 100131","color":"#717D7E","textColor":"white","url":"link.php?j=MTAwMTMx"},{"id":"100132","start":"2019-06-19","end":"2019-06-21","title":"(ME) 10x10 100132","color":"#717D7E","textColor":"white","url":"link.php?j=MTAwMTMy"},{"id":"100138","start":"2019-06-24","end":"2019-06-26","title":"(ML) 20x20 (2 of 2) 100138","color":"#F1C40F","textColor":"black","url":"link.php?j=MTAwMTM4"},{"id":"100139","start":"2019-08-25","end":"2019-08-27","title":"(ML) 10x20 (2 of 3) 100139","color":"#28B463","textColor":"white","url":"link.php?j=MTAwMTM5"},{"id":"100163","start":"2018-11-03","end":"2018-11-07","title":"(JG) 20x30 pull & prep 100163","color":"#717D7E","textColor":"white","url":"link.php?j=MTAwMTYz"}]
```

The feed data does not include any repetitions.  And the numeric "more + " link does not count entries more than once.  However the popup includes duplicates.

Here are a couple more screenshots to highlight one day in particular, June 6, 2019. There are  6 events on this date, one of which 100996 is repeated 6 times in the popup while the others are not.  The feed data does not include 6 entries for 100996, only one.

[image: month view]

There is something in the popup code that is duplicating events, possibly related to when the events span days or weeks.

[image: day view]

Comment: you'll need to show us some code and sample data. We can't fix what we can't see. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling `$('#calendar').fullCalendar()` twice? And can we see sample events data (that's generated by the PHP file - `feed.php`)?

Comment: there is filtering on the calendar so first default is 'all' and second callback enables filtering

Comment: I used the sample data with [this Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrqjKN/left/?editors=0010) (FullCalendar 3.10.0 with jQuery 3.3.1) and I'm not having the issue raised in the question. So if you could create a Pen which reproduces the issue, then maybe we can help.

Comment: take a look at the new images I added.  I examined the raw json sent from the feed to the fullcalendar to process.  It only contains 1 entry for 100996.  Yet, by the time the code reaches line 5217 at eventFootprintToSegs: function(eventFootprint, constraintRange) , the duplicates are present.  I'm currently trying to remove the dups from that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I altered fullcalendar.js function that produces the date popup by removing the duplicate events from the popup before they are displayed, code block is about line 8390. hope this helps someone else save some time. Saw similar bug reports of this on fullcalendar github page.

original

```
resliceDaySegs: function(segs, dayDate) {
  var dayStart = dayDate.clone();
  var dayEnd = dayStart.clone().add(1, 'days');
  var dayRange = new UnzonedRange(dayStart, dayEnd);
  var newSegs = [];
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < segs.length; i++) {
    newSegs.push.apply(newSegs, this.eventFootprintToSegs(segs[i].footprint, dayRange));
  }
  this.sortEventSegs(newSegs);
  return newSegs;
},
```

to this

```
resliceDaySegs: function(segs, dayDate) {
    var dayStart = dayDate.clone();
    var dayEnd = dayStart.clone().add(1, 'days');
    var dayRange = new UnzonedRange(dayStart, dayEnd);
    var newSegs = [];
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < segs.length; i++) {
        newSegs.push.apply(newSegs, // append
            this.eventFootprintToSegs(segs[i].footprint, dayRange)
        );
    }

    var unique = [];
    var newSegsX = [];

    $.each(newSegs, function(i,el){

        if($.inArray(el.footprint.eventDef.id, unique) === -1){
            unique.push(el.footprint.eventDef.id);
            newSegsX.push(el);
        } 
    });

    this.sortEventSegs(newSegsX);
    return newSegsX;
},
```